# What is the Strange Souvenir used for?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

[image]
Any ideas what's this for? I've searched, couldn't find anything.

Comment: It could be a hint about the next gen

Comment: The hiker that you get it from notes: "it's not Kanto, Johto, Hoenn, Sinnoh, or Unova." So it may be some item used for a possible expansion of X/Y (speculation of course), or maybe even a third "Z" game. I'm sure it's a hidden secret from GameFreak that we will eventually find out.

Comment: It could be related to the 3 un-released legendaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the item does nothing as of December 2016, the description has been changed in Pokemon Sun & Moon:

> An ornament depicting a mysterious Pokémon that has been venerated as a guardian deity for an extremely long time in the Alola region.

So we know that it represents a mysterious (perhaps Legendary) Pokemon in the Alola region.

Answer (score 4):

There have been other items like this.  In Gen 4 you can get a box from a Team Rocket member that gives you a TM in gen 5.  The only thing we can sorta know for sure is that it is some sort of event item but as to what it does we can only guess.  It may be a year or two before we know what Gamefreak intends to do with this or it may just be nothing at all.

Answer (score -3):

Its really just a junk item that's there to make us excited for Pokemon 7th gen.  Maybe its from the region in so called Pokemon plus, minus that's being talked about (Google it if you don't know what I'm talking about) there have been items like this in the past

Answer (score -4):

Here's my theory:

We know the Strange Souvenir is from the Hiker's own region, a currently unknown and unnamed region. The Strange Souvenir, as it's description suggests, is a Pokémon that is hailed as a protector of sorts in that region.

The Strange Souvenir looks a lot like one of those Easter Island heads, or moai, doesn't it? Some historical theories suggests moai were the "embodiment of powerful living or former chiefs". Other theories suggests moai are "protectors of Easter Island".

Easter Island's actual name is Isla de Pascua. It is a special territory of Chilé.

Generation VII's real-life location confirmed.

Comment: This is too speculative to be a useful answer.

Answer (score -4):

I think it is for opening the 3 locked doors in route 13 (lumiose bad lands)